# MOT in UK, is there a tolerance time when the MOT is expired?

Tags: service

My MOT expires next month and I need to renew it, however I have a flight to take in that period and I'll be back two days after the expiration date. I need to bring the car to the airport and leave it there for 1 week, for many reasons it is convenient to me to do so. I was wondering if there's a tolerance time where I can keep my car without MOT. Something like: "Ok your MOT is expired, but you have to renew it in one week".

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from having it done early?

Comment: Yes, the latest date I've been proposed is 3 weeks earlier... If possible I'd like to avoid that (because it means I'm wasting one month of the current MOT)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you can have it done **1 month before the expiry date, minus 1 day** and you will still preserve the full length of your MOT. 
This is done for convenience and to allow time for repairs. I always take mine at the earliest opportunity so I can plan for any potential problems.

Example:
"If your MOT runs out on 15 May, the earliest you can get an MOT to keep the same renewal date for next year is 16 April." [Source](https://www.gov.uk/getting-an-mot/when-to-get-an-mot)

Secondly, if it does expire, you **can technically drive it to the MOT test garage** if you can prove you have an appointment there for an MOT.
In other words, if your MOT expires, you cannot use your car on the public roads (**your insurance is also invalidated**), however, the exception is if you are driving to have it tested for MOT.

All of this information is at the gov [website.](https://www.gov.uk/getting-an-mot/when-to-get-an-mot)

So, just take it now before your trip, you won't lose the month if its within 1 month minus 1 day.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote (now deleted) but you have references, well done.

Comment: My MOT expires the 16th of April, so If do the test tomorrow say (22nd of March), I would still keep using the current one until it expires and then I would use the new one since I'll have done the MOT test one month minus 1 day in advance, is this understanding correct?

Comment: Ring the MOT station and check with them - the answer is clear.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty clear from the gov website example. You can take it 1 month less 1 day than the current expiry. Principally, you won't be "using the current one", its just the new one will  start earlier, i.e. the new one will be for 13 months. Read the gov website, its actually very useful and easy to find information.

Comment: The example seems pretty clear... 1 month minus 1 day is the earliest date I can do MOT in order to keep the same renewal date. Which means in my case doesn't make any difference if I do it now or 1 day before the expiration date, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - in your case, if you had it tested on the 22nd of March, it would expire on the 16th April 2018. If you left it until you got back, it would be illegal for you to drive it home from the airport!

Comment: Unless he goes directly to the test station with a pre-booked slot...